# Clearing sharedpreferences in alarmreciever

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I've been struggling for a while with this problem. I need to uncheck and reenable my checkboxes when the alarm receiver pops, but it doesn't work for some reason.

I've tried to do it with sharedpreferences

TaskFragment.kt

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    binding = FragmentTaskBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

    val sharedPrefs = requireActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    binding.checkTaskOne.isChecked = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("checkbox1", false)
    binding.checkTaskTwo.isChecked = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("checkbox2", false)
    binding.checkTaskThree.isChecked = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("checkbox3", false)

    binding.checkTaskOne.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
        sharedPrefs.edit().putBoolean("checkbox1", isChecked).apply()
        updateCheckboxes()
    }
    binding.checkTaskTwo.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
        sharedPrefs.edit().putBoolean("checkbox2", isChecked).apply()
        updateCheckboxes()
    }
    binding.checkTaskThree.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
        sharedPrefs.edit().putBoolean("checkbox3", isChecked).apply()
        updateCheckboxes()
    }
    return binding.root
}

private fun updateCheckboxes() {
    val allChecked = binding.checkTaskOne.isChecked && binding.checkTaskTwo.isChecked && binding.checkTaskThree.isChecked
    binding.checkTaskOne.isEnabled = !allChecked || binding.checkTaskOne.isChecked
    binding.checkTaskTwo.isEnabled = !allChecked || binding.checkTaskTwo.isChecked
    binding.checkTaskThree.isEnabled = !allChecked || binding.checkTaskThree.isChecked

    if (allChecked) {
        binding.checkTaskOne.isEnabled = false
        binding.checkTaskTwo.isEnabled = false
        binding.checkTaskThree.isEnabled = false
        binding.textView2.setText(R.string.splneno)
    }
```

this saves my states.

AlarmReciever.kt

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        Log.i("NOTE","Notifying")

    val notificationUtils = NotiUtils(context)
        val notification = notificationUtils.getNotificationBuilder().build()
        notificationUtils.getManager().notify(150, notification)

    val sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    sharedPrefs.edit().clear().apply()
}
```

It pushes the notification, so the alarm should work normally, but it just doesn't seem to do anything with the checkboxes even when it should. Anybody know why it doesn't? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what `clear the checkboxes` exactly mean for you?

Comment: "I need to clean my checkboxes when the alarm receiver pops" - what does that mean?

Comment: it means that i want to uncheck and reenable the checkboxes with alarmreciever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code clears the shared preferences but that's it. There's no logic in to react to that nor your AlarmReceiver contains code to notify TaskFragment it needs to update. You need to i.e. use LocalBroadcastReceiver in your receiver to shout out about the event:

```kotlin
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    ...

    val updateCheckboxesIntent = Intent("com.example.yourapp.UPDATE_CHECKBOXES")
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context)
          .sendBroadcast(updateCheckboxesIntent)
}
```

and then make your fragment listen to that broadcast:

```kotlin
class TaskActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    ...

    private val updateCheckboxesReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            // do whatever you need
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
            updateCheckboxesReceiver,
            IntentFilter("com.example.yourapp.UPDATE_CHECKBOXES")
        )
    }

    override fun onPause() {
         super.onPause()
         LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
               .unregisterReceiver(updateCheckboxesReceiver)
    }
}
```

Comment: that only works when the fragment is on the screen if I'm not mistaken

Comment: sure. If it's not then why bother its ui? and when it gets resumed you should set up UI in i.e. onResume() anyway

Comment: well, the thing is, i want to set the new checkbox states even when the app is not on. The alarm goes off daily at 8 am. I'm sorry, I'm still quite a beginner in Kotlin

Comment: ive heard that clearing the sharedpreferences should work, but if it doesn't, my fault.

Comment: `i want to set the new checkbox states even when the app is not on` what for? it makes no sense. All you need is to reflect current state when fragment returns. And that's what onResume() is for. Just create separate function to update the UI and call it either from onResume and from the local broadcast receiver's onReceive - that should cover both cases.

Comment: so you mean that onResume checks if the alarm was triggered and if it was, it will call the intent which will update the checkboxes when the fragment is on screen?

Comment: No. in fragment's onResume all you need to do to stay up to date is to read shared preferences again and set up the checkboxes according to current state you read. You do not care when state changed (or if ever). You just set the UI according to the current state, whatever that state is.

Comment: Please note it is completely irrelevant for the fragment both *if* and *how* the shared preferences state changed. You do not care. All you need to do is to show current state when you pop to front. And then, to make UX better, you also want the UI to automatically update when prefs changed. And that's why we use LocalBroadcast. But this is NOT a broadcast of/for AlarmReceiver. It's generic event that indicates "prefs changed". Anything can send it and anything could listen to it and react if needed.

Comment: ok, i finally made it work, thank you so much!